# Entity Framework - Code First Migrations : Existing Constraints

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have an application were I was using Code First without migrations, but now I want to switch over to Code First with Migrations. When running the migrations, the sql script has checks for constraints that follow the pattern of

```
FK_dbo.[ChildTableName]_dbo.[ParentTableName]_[ChildColumnName]
```

It will remove those constraints and re-add them after doing the changes it needs. The problem that I am running into is that I have existing constraints that Entity Framework doesn't detect, so I end up with duplicate constraints.

For example, my database originally had a constraint called FK_UserConfig_User_User_ID, and now entity framework created a duplicate constraint called FK_dbo.UserConfig_dbo.User_User_ID. Is there a way to get Entity Framework to detect existing constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name you want in the Up() code. So where you see:

```
CreateTable("ParentTable"
...
.ForeignKey("ChildTable", t => t.ParentId, cascadeDelete: true)
```

There is another override that takes the name:

```
.ForeignKey("ChildTable", t => t.ParentId, cascadeDelete: true, name: "FK_UserConfig_User_User_ID")
```